# write.table scrambles csv file in ArcGIS

Tags: r, csv, arcgis, write.table

I have posted this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/86705/10926) to a GIS forum but am asking here because there are two sides to this coin - and I am sure ArcGIS people will tell me to ask R people - so here I am asking the R people.  I am trying to bring in and create a shape file from an output file generated by R scripting.  So, I write my csv file using:

```
write.table(PointData, paste(RootOutputFileName,"SSF_MvtMetrics_",Date,".csv", sep = ""), row.names = F, sep = ",")
```

PointData is simply a data frame.

```
   structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("3311_1", 
"3313_1", "3313_2", "3344_1", "3344_2", "3344_3", "3348_1", "3349_1", 
"3350_1", "3352_1", "3352_2", "3352_3", "3353_1", "3353_2", "3353_3", 
"3355_1", "3355_2", "3602_1", "7615_1", "7616_1", "7616_2", "7617_1", 
"7617_2", "7617_3", "7618_1", "7618_2", "7618_3", "7619_1", "7619_2"
), class = "factor"), Date_Time = structure(c(1286529600, 1286529600, 
1286529600, 1286529600, 1286529600, 1286529600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), moose = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L), .Label = c("F01001", "F070014a", "F07002", "F07005", 
"F07006", "F07010", "F07011", "F07020", "F07021", "F10004", "F10008", 
"F10009", "F98015", "M07012a", "M10011"), class = "factor"), 
    trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), x = c(1476079, 1475943.59345214, 
    1476063.09369225, 1476103.7686023, 1476191.98817498, 1475969.09165391
    ), y = c(6620355, 6620153.61044344, 6620319.54350105, 6620364.30580689, 
    6620189.01655503, 6620438.97062545), label = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("after", "before", "dog", 
    "End before", "End Before", "end dog", "End dog", "no dog", 
    "resettles", "Start after", "start dog"), class = "factor"), 
    label.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("after", 
    "before", "dog", "no dog", "resettles"), class = "factor"), 
    dog = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Ida", 
    "Ludde", "Tanja"), class = "factor"), Reproduction = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Calf", "No Calf"), class = "factor"), 
    Position = c("End", "End", "End", "End", "End", "End"), EvalPt = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), DistX = c(-13, -148.406547861864, -28.9063077468417, 
    11.7686022959398, 99.9881749765198, -122.908346089521), DistY = c(26, 
    -175.389556564022, -9.45649895283019, 35.3058068878195, -139.983444967128, 
    109.970625448519), Dist = c(29.0688837074973, 229.752040252094, 
    30.4138126514911, 37.2155881318568, 172.026160801199, 164.924225024706
    ), Heading = c(5.81953769817878, 3.8438495850988, 4.39621994880961, 
    0.321750554396642, 2.52134316760697, 5.44228863853642), TimeDif = c(0.166666666666667, 
    0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
    0.166666666666667, 0.166666666666667), Velocity = c(174.413302244984, 
    1378.51224151257, 182.482875908947, 223.293528791141, 1032.15696480719, 
    989.545350148239), Angle = c(2.67794504458899, 0.702256931509007, 
    1.25462729521981, 3.46334320798643, 5.66293582119676, 2.30069598494663
    ), LocType = c("Obs", "rand", "rand", "rand", "rand", "rand"
    ), LocNum = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), RandId = 0:5), .Names = c("ID", 
"Date_Time", "moose", "trial", "x", "y", "label", "label.1", 
"dog", "Reproduction", "Position", "EvalPt", "DistX", "DistY", 
"Dist", "Heading", "TimeDif", "Velocity", "Angle", "LocType", 
"LocNum", "RandId"), row.names = c("3", "2", "31", "4", "5", 
"6"), class = "data.frame")
```

When I bring this into ArcGIS and open the table things get scrambled as [described in my other post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/86705/10926).

I am assuming something is happening with the `write.table` command and how Ive set the `sep = ","` but I really do not know.  Ive never had problems before when I simply use `write.csv`.  I do not understand why/how R writes the objects with or without formatting code that is then read by ArcGIS.

In R, to generate the data for this csv file - I have set `as.POSIXct(strptime(loc$Date_Time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",tz="GMT"),tz="GMT")`

I do not know where it is getting the values for moose.x or moose.y from at all, or the ID_X or ID_Y, why it is changing the time in the date_time column or why some of the values in the x column are coming out as numbers but others are coming out as 0.

Im not trying to cross post, and apologize if my linking to the other question is in bad form - I just didn't want to retype everything, rather ask if anyone has come across this problem before and if there is something I can add to my code that would keep the structure formatting to work in these other programs outside of R.

Comment: Add the output of `dput(head(MovData1))` to your question.

Comment: @Roland I had done that in the other post - which was what I was trying to avoid - replicating the question completely.  In the other post are the head and str for the output from R.  Is this bad form to have the question linked across?  Should I duplicate the content here too?

Comment: We don't want printed output, but something we can use to reproduce exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: @Roland Ive updated to include the head as you have suggested

Comment: `csv` file produced by your code is allright (on my PC). I don't see the problem even in the first post - it seems to be same number of records in every column - they are not formated, but they should be fine. Could you try to use another separator (semicolon, tab) and see, if there is problem then?

Comment: @Zbynek that is so strange.  Ive just now copied my own data from above, used the write.table command from above and I STILL get new columns of data being added, the removal of data where "x" and "y" and DistX and DistY columns are now all NA's and the Date_Time column now reads all time as 2010-10-08 09:20:00 for every point when I bring it into ArcGIS but it reads just fine in Excel - no missing no new columns nothing strange in Excel - just in ArcGIS.

Comment: Can ArcGIS read dbf? If so, you can try to save data using `write.dbf` from `foreign` package

Comment: Sounds like ArcGIS is not happy with column names you have. Perhaps it automatically splits on `X`, for example? What happens if you read the file into Excel (OK by your comment), then "save as" to a new text-only or csv file, and try to read that into ArcGIS?  One other thing - does anyone know if packages like `foreign` have a direct ArcGIS-format I/O function?

Comment: @Zbynek yes ArcGIS can read dbf files which is another potential work around. As I mentioned so far my best solution is to output the file as a csv, open it in Excel and save as an xls and then open that in ArcGIS. With this work around, I get no mysterious new columns of strange numbers and no missing data.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If ArcGIS doesn't like the names I sort of understand, but then the typical reaction of ArcGIS is to rename it, not generate entirely new columns of data or exclude some data but not others within a column.

Comment: did you try to use write.csv instead? did you tried to replace "label.1" by "label_1"? as well as replacing "Reproduction" with a shorter name?

Comment: @A.R Changing the names of other columns still does not explain the addition of 2 new columns of data. Additionally, names like label.1 work fine with the "." or "_" either way.  Reproduction could be shortened, but that is not a column I have issues with.